# I'm getting results that aren't coherent with my code in python. Need to omit some caracters for my letter frequency code but they still appear

Tags: python, punctuation

I was coding a little thing to calculate the number of each letter in a text file, calculate their frequency and compare them with [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Letter_frequency), I did it in English and no problem but when I swapped to a french text file, I got some odd things appearing. First here's my code:

```
from unidecode import unidecode
fhand = open('samplefr.txt')
c = dict()
total = 0
for line in fhand:
    line = line.rstrip()
    line = line.replace(" ","")
    line = line.translate(line.maketrans('','',string.punctuation))
    line = line.lower()
    line = unidecode(line, "utf-8")
    for words in line:
        total = total + 1
        c[words] = c.get(words,0)+1
print(total)
f = sorted([(v,k) for k,v in c.items()])
print(f)
for v in f:
    print(v[1],'=',v[0]/total*100, '%')
```

[Here are the results I get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b9NoZ.png)
I don't understand why the characters " ' < > ( ) and even a whitespace are appearing in the results. Thanks for any help.

Comment: In `for words in line`, if `line` is a string, then you will loop over that **characters** of that string, not its words.

Comment: Nevermind, I want to eat and when I came back I thought that what if the ```line = unidecode(line, "utf-8")``` was earlier in the code. I changed it and it was the answer. Didn't think about it before but getting rid of the ' or " etc... before removing the punctuation was logical

Answer (score 0):

For the problem with the white spaces, it could be that the text contains a different kind of whitespace. Unicode contains multiple white spaces ([See here](https://jkorpela.fi/chars/spaces.html)) and you only filter out one in this line:

`line = line.replace(" ","")`

I think the same problem could be with the other symbols. I tested your code manually and it works when I create a string with the symbols you mentioned.

It is difficult to look further into the problem without the input file. I would suggest that you check the encoding of the file. Furthermore, look if the unicode of the symbols in your text are the same as the unicode of the symbols that you filter out in your code.